# Why multiple inserts do not work?

Tags: php, mongodb

I try to populate my `mongodb` collection with large data in order to test performance. I first tried to do it in a loop like this:

```
while($i <= 1000000){
    $collection->insert($_POST);
}
```

And then I tried this way:

```
$collection->insert($_POST);
$collection->insert($_POST);
...
$collection->insert($_POST);
```

But in both situations only one row was added. Why is that?

Comment: It is probably because of the _id of POST, with same id, you are just replacing the last one (in your case, the first one) and you will have just one document, change the id field

Comment: That is right. But it is very interesting. print_r shows me that POST get _id attribute right after all inserts. Before that it does not have any _id attribute. For some reason `insert` alters the structure of POST.

Comment: every root document have to have the _id field in their structures, i_id could be almost anything, use **$i** for your _id

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but if performance is a concern, have you looked into [bulk inserts](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.insert/#Bulk.insert)? It might suit your needs better.